# How can I identify upscaled images?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

Are there any methods that I may employ to identify 'false' 4K images? i.e. Images that have been upscaled to 4K from 720p/1080p.

I have tried searching but I have mainly only found methods to upscale images with different methods like Billinear, Bicubic, Lanczos , SRCNN and EDSR.

How may I then identify these images that have been upscaled from a lower resolution from 'truly 4K' images?

I currently have a dataset of 200 'true' 4K images that I will downscale and upscale again using one of the methods stated above. Is there a way I can train a model to differentiate these images in a given image dataset? This should give me at least 400 images to work with, with 2 categories. True 4K and Upscaled 4K.

Is there a machine learning model I should use? So far I am new to the field of computer vision, digital image processing, machine learning in general and have only had experience with Convolutional Neural Network Image Classifiers. Can a CNN be used to train a model to identify such images? Or is a machine learning approach not suitable in this case?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Following @CAFEBABE suggestion, I've split these 4K images (real, lanczos upscaled and bicubic upscaled from 1080p) into 51200 images of 240x135 for each category and put them into a CNN as shown below.

```
model = Sequential() 

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape = (135, 240, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 2 hidden layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

# The output layer with 3 neurons, for 3 classes
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# Compiling the model using some basic parameters
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
              ,optimizer="adam"
              ,metrics=["accuracy"])
```

However, my model does not seem to be learning based on upscaling and is instead trying to categorise based on what the image is; I am getting accuracies of 33% (purely random)

Is CNN able to be used for this problem, or is there something I missed with my model?

Answer (score 1):

You should try.

Short message potentially you can do it with a CNN, trained on the two class problem upscaled/not upscaled. I actually would train it to even identify the method, as it seems to be an easier problem. I guess you need more images though. Secondly to train a CNN on such large resolution images is a pain in the neck.

hence I'd follow the following approach:

(step1) build a dataset on lower resolution patches from large scale images. So a 4096 × 2160 consists basically out of 16 1024x540 image datasets and so on. To make it realistically trainable build up a dataset of images with resolution 227x240 from any source.

(step2) down and upscale these images like you would do with the high res images. For this step I would not use the patches itself but the original high-res images

(step3) Train a NN to identify.

(step4) Calculate for each image who well it helps to solve the problem (entropy good vs bad)

(step5) build a segmentation model which selects from an image the best region(s) to solve the problem. So which 227x240 patches out ouf a 4k images help you to identify the downscaling. The segmentation does not need to be trained on the full resolution image. Assumption is that you will not be able to identify certain upscaling methods on uniform coloured image regions.

(loop) but use in step1 the segmentation model to identify patches.

Comment: In step 2, after i have down and upscaled the original high-res images, I should also split these upscaled images into 16 1024x520 images, so that I have similar images from step 1 and step 2?

Comment: I would go for even more/even smaller patches. training a NN of 1024x520 takes an extremly long time. the artefacts of scaling are visible on very small image regions. The tricky part is to find the right region. This depends on the algorithm. Most algorithm generate "smooth results". This smoothness stays even after eg sharpening. However, to avoid this smoothness artificial detail (noise) might be added to trick detection. I expect a GAN doing sth. along this line.

Comment: So i've just tested this out: from my 200 4K images dataset, I split it into 51200 240x135 images, along with the same images that I've downscaled and upscaled with lanczos and bicubic to form 3 separate categories. Putting it into a CNN model, the model does not seem to be learning and giving me 33% (purely random) Is there another way to do this with machine learning?

Comment: Not beating the null hypothesis is extremely surprising. To check the pipeline I'd recommend to downscale further. Also use bilinear interpolation as baseline. At some point it should be possible. In bicubic interpolation a 4x4 grid should have certain relations. This imho also hints  at the convolutions kernel size

Comment: In extension: did you achieve on train or on test set?

Comment: Both train and test set were giving similar results; I've also tried shuffled and non-shuffled datasets. I will try using billinear and 4K, just 2 categories. That should give me a clear understanding of whether CNN could be used. Otherwise, I've been reading about Difference of Gaussian which hopefully can be used to classify them as well.

Comment: To provide a potentially better input you can also down/upscale the input and calculate differences. 4k images should have a higher noise level. on quadratic interpolated images you see clear lines from the typical overshooting. However, this requires that you use similar parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Try out GAN for this. It will help you to solve this problem

Comment: Been reading about GAN for the past hour, seems like it is exactly what I'm looking for. Cheers

Comment: Yes Exactly what i have said

Comment: How should a GAN help in this? GANs would help you to build a method to UpScale images in a way that it can not be identified using a CNN or any other NN

Comment: It seems I was mistaken - I thought that the discriminator (that was trained with the generator in GAN) would be able to be used individually, to identify if the upscaled images are "real 4K images".

Comment: GAN Feature Descriptor can be used to make this prediction

Comment: May i request that you elaborate on how I may be able to use GAN for this prediction?